# Changing only the thickness but not the length of a line segment in R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I can **ONLY** increase the **thickness** of the line segment (**which is supposed to go from -2 to 2**) in my R plot **without** increasing the length of it? (***see my R code below***)

***Note*:** Apparently, `lwd` proportionally increases the **length** in addition to the **thickness of a line segment**. **For example,** in the plot below, even though the line segment is set to go from -2 to 2, the length of the red line segment has gone beyond -2 and 2.

[image]

**Here is my R code:**

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, lwd = 3)
segments(-2, 0, 2, 0, col = 'red', lend = 2, lwd = 20)
```

Comment: For future reference `?par` contains a full list of all graphical parameters that can help with solving issues like this. There are only 3 unique options for `lend=`, `0` by default, the `2` you used, and the `1` you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want `lend = 1` or `lend = "butt"`

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, lwd = 3)
segments(-2, 0, 2, 0, col = 'red', lwd = 20, lend = "butt")
```

And workaround using `polygon`

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, lwd = 3)
polygon(x = c(-2,2,2,-2), y = c(0,0,0.02,0.02), col = "red", border = NA)
```

Comment: @parvinkarimi - the thickness of the `segments` line is perfectly 50% either side of 0 on the y-axis - try `abline(h=0)` to see the line straight through the middle.

Comment: @parvinkarimi - because that makes no sense. If you are drawing a segment aligned to a particular point, every part of that segment should be as close as possible to the specified point.